# Is there anyway to update a column of data in SQL Database only when changes are detected?

Tags: python

I am currently using SQL Alchemy to create a database and I want to enable users to update the database by using an API end point by uploading a csv file If ever necessary.
[This is the CSV file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxP72.png)

The column names are the same as my database, My API end points are working and I can receive the CSV through a jsonified version of the CSV. I was wondering how to I update my database if say there's a change in the construction programme for a given date.

Thank you in advance ( It's my first time posting, forgive me for the lack of details and explaination)

Comment: You need to store the dynamic field with values, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.